# Need advice on serial bytes reading optimization

Tags: esp8266

I am doing some device serial data read and publishing values to MQTT. Using ESP8266 for this.

Currenty I request serial device by sending a command and parse all byte values individually, how to do this in better way ?

each byte parse is done in such way:

```
float Heat = (float)data[38];


  sprintf(mqtt_topic, "%s/%s", mqtt_topic_base, "Temp"); mqtt_client.publish(mqtt_topic, String(Temp).c_str());

float Power = (float)data[39];
......
..... and etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle it is ok to use your way, but a simple improvement is to change the magic numbers (38, 39) to constants or define:

```
const int offset_heat = 38;

…

float Heat = (float)data[offset_heat];
```

or a define:

```
#define OFFSET_HEAT 38

…

float Heat = (float)data[OFFSET_HEAT];
```

If all values are consecutive you can keep a variable to read the values:

```
int offset = 38; // Normally starts at 0 assuming you read values from the start

float heat = (float) readByte(&offset);

…

int readByte(uint8_t* offset)
{
    int value = data[*offset];
    (*offset)++;
    return value;
}
```

This increases the offset after reading the value.

Some remarks:

- It's a convention not to use capitals for local variables (so change Heat to heat)
- You don't use the Heat variable in `sprintf`, maybe this is intentional.

Comment: sorry in sprintf I didnt changed on this exaple, misstake from me :)

Comment: No problem, for the solution it doesn't change